# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ('Setting RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY is not of type', <class 'str'>)

Tags: python, recaptcha, otree

Good morning, I am trying to use a Google captcha in Otree, I installed recaptcha and create an account that gave me the keys, but when I run the powershell it shows me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\otree_startup\__init__.py", line 202, in do_django_setup
    django.setup()
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\captcha\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    "Setting %s is not of type" % variable, instance_type
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ('Setting RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY is not of type', <class 'str'>)
```

This is the code that I have in my settings, the enviroment.get code is to run the experiment on Heroku.

RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = '**RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY**'

RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = '**RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY**'

RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = environ.get('RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY')

RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = environ.get('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY')

The key are numbers and I dont know how to make the captcha works, someone can give a idea??

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with that module and what I had done was:

in `settings.py` wrap keys with `str()`:

```
RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY = str('YOUR_RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY')
RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY = str('YOUR_RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY')
```

I checked it out by inserting debug prints directly into the `site-packages\captcha\__init__.py` like this:

```
SETTINGS_TYPES = {
    "RECAPTCHA_DOMAIN": str,
    "RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY": str,
    "RECAPTCHA_PROXY": dict,
    "RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY": str,
    "RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_REQUEST_TIMEOUT": int,
}

print(settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY) # <--added
print(type(settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY)) # <--added

# Validate settings types.
for variable, instance_type in SETTINGS_TYPES.items():
    if hasattr(settings, variable) \
            and not isinstance(getattr(settings, variable), instance_type):
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "Setting %s is not of type" % variable, instance_type
        )
```

and then I typed `python manage.py shell` to see the output. And really, type of the RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY was `unicode` instead of `str`.